# How can I adjust my third vector position?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I adjust my third vector position?
I want the vector to start from the origin (0,0) and point to the (4,-7) position, which is the green one in the picture. How to design it?
Attach my code as below, thank you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
V = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])
origin= [0], [0]
plt.quiver( *origin, V[:,0], V[:,1], color=['r','b','g'], scale=21)
plt.show()
```

[image: greenline error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is how [`quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
V = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])
origin = np.array([[0,0] for _ in range(3)])
plt.quiver(origin[:,0], origin[:,1], V[:,0], V[:,1], 
           color=['r','b','g'], scale=21)
plt.show()
```

note that the `scale` will shorten the vectors; this way they will not point at the vectors you have given, but in their direction and scaled down.